# Symfony2 dynamically assign attr to form field

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I'm in a situation where I want to be able to dynamically set the `required=true/false` option or the `array(...other stuff..., 'class' => ' hidden')` of a form field.

The context is the following: there is a "Project" entity with some fields. When I create other entities with forms I want to check some attributes of the Project entity and make decisions on the visibility/requiredness of certain fields of the entity I'm creating.

For example if a Project is with attribute "timePressure=high" then a field of a given entity is not required (but is visible). If there are other conditions it becomes invisible etc...

So basically I was hoping to call a function inside each `->add()` of the form builder to spit out the relevant portions (e.g. that function would return a string with "required=true" or the other related to the hidden class). The thing is that the function should take as arguments: the projectID (ok, this can be passed as options of the form builder), the class and the field we are talking about to decide. I was envisioning something like:

```
->add('background', 'textarea', array('attr' => array('rows' => 4, functionToDecideIfInvisible($projectId)), functionToDecideRequiredness($projectId)))
```

The two function would return the string `'class' => ' hidden'` and `required=true` (or false)

I'd like to avoid to having to specify the field name (in this case `background`) to avoid code repetition.

Can this be done?

Other suggestions on how to solve the thing?

Thank you!

SN

Answer (score 2):

What you need are Form Events:  http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#cookbook-form-events-underlying-data

They allow you to modify your form based on your data.

You create you project form in the controller:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new ProjectType(), $project, array(
    'action' => $this->generateUrl('project.edit'),
    'method' => 'POST',
));
```

Then you add the FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA listener:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
        $project = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        // check timePressure on the Project object
        if ('high' === $project->timePressure) {
            $form->add('timePressure', 'text', array(
                'required' => false
            );
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: That's an interesting feature I did not know...but I could achieve the same without the event listener if I want to embed the logic there. I could simply check the project field and add a field in a way or another. But what I was looking for is a way to query the DB where I have a list of all possible fields, and all the project fields. I'd like to call the function inside the "add" and the function would:1)get the field form which it was called, 2) check the DB, return the desired attribute/class. Is that even possible?

Comment: @SergioNegri, I think your approach is wrong. You can't call your function inside the "add". Instead you should call the "add" function inside the event listener with different attributes/classes.

Comment: @SpartakusMs I read the link you provided. I'm wondering what's the value added of a listener when you can build straight away the form the way you like, without all this listening stuff...I'm probably missing something, there must be a reason :/

Comment: @SergioNegri, It is a much cleaner way to do things. There are more types of events `PRE_SET_DATA`, `POST_SET_DATA`, `PRE_SUBMIT`, `SUBMIT`, `POST_SUBMIT`. They are made for you to modify the form in different moment of the request based on the data you have or not.

Comment: Ok, as it's not that heavy I'll add the event listener just in case. But the rest remains intact (I mean calling the functions inside). Otherwise I'm really replicating a lot of code (3 add lines for each add, depending on the result of the function...)

Answer (score -1):

I found a way to do it.

My add would be like:

```
->add('background', 'textarea', array_merge($this->vr->fieldReq(get_class($this), 
'background', $projectID), array('attr' => array_merge(array('rows' => 4, ),
$this->vr->fieldCssClass(get_class($this), 'background', $projectID) ) )))
```

To do that I had to define the form as service, plus I created another class as service (the one which holds the two methods I need).

This is the class:

```
class FieldReqAndCssClass
{
public function fieldReq($parentEntity, $field, $projectID)
    {
    $required = array();
    $required['required'] = false; //do stuff on the database instead of setting it to false hardcoded
    return $required;
    }

public function fieldCssClass($parentEntity, $field, $projectID)
    {
    $cssClass= array();
    //do stuff on the database instead of setting the class as hidden hardcoded
    //$cssClass['class'] = ' hidden';
    $cssClass['class'] = '';
    return $cssClass;
    }
}
```

Of course in my form I had to:

```
public function __construct(\AppBundle\Util\FieldReqAndCssClass $fieldReqAndCssClass)
{
$this->vr = $fieldReqAndCssClass; // vr stands for visibility and requiredness
}
```

And these are the two services:

```
app_bundle.field_req_and_css_class:
    class: AppBundle\Util\FieldReqAndCssClass
    arguments: []

app_bundle.form.type.projectdetail:
    class: AppBundle\Form\Type\ProjectDetailFormType
    arguments: [@app_bundle.field_req_and_css_class]
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: ProjectDetail }
```

Of course here in the first service I'll need to inject the entity manager and add it to the construct, and probably also in the form service, but the basic skeleton is working :)

I'm a happy man :)

**EDIT**
The only problem of the above is that it makes hidden the widget but not the label. To fix it:

```
->add('background', 'textarea', array_merge($vr->fieldReq($myClass,
'background', $project), array('label_attr' => $vr->fieldCssClass($myClass, 
'background', $project),'attr' => array_merge(array('rows' => 4, ), 
$vr->fieldCssClass($myClass, 'background', $project) ) )))
```

Obviously before I have to declare:

```
$myClass = get_class($this);
$vr = $this->vr;
```